# Create JavaScript array of a negative number series which decreases in increments of -100 based on a single integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a JavaScript array of values decreasing in increments of -100%. The number of increments will be dictated by a variable.

#### Example 1.

```js
var items = 3;
var position = [ "0", "-100%", "-200%" ];
```

#### Example 2.

```js
var items = 5;
var position = [ "0", "-100%", "-200%", "-300%", "-400%" ];
```

I've managed to create the list of numbers:

```js
var end = (items - 1) * -100;
for (var j = 0; j >= end; j-=100)
    position[position.length] = j;
```

But I'm struggling to add the `%` unit and I'm worried the `-=` approach is bad practice.

Comment: You can just append the symbol to the end of the value: `... = j + '%';`. Also, a negative step is not bad practice.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan, whilst searching for a solution I remember reading a bad practice comment about negative steps, I guess it was just one opinion or my misinterpretation, thank you for clarifying and the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and map the values.

```js
const getArray = length  => Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i ? `-${100 * i}%` : '0');

console.log(getArray(3));
```